# Solicitation of a Security

Tags: stocks, legal

Question on solicitation  of securities for a mother & son in a joint account. All activity historically had been done through mother, and then when son became older the responsibility was through son. Since his investment objectives were different we decided to only continue some of the growth objectives and stocks that mother had been buying, and majority allocated to income to meet son's income needs. Since son now has authority and he wants only some of his mom's stocks with more invested for income, here is the question. If we then purchase two of the stocks his mom had, is this considered a solicited or unsolicited transaction? Please give me your opinion or interpretation. Thanks.

Comment: Country?  Possibly state or province.  This sounds like a legal distinction.  If so, jurisdiction is going to be important.  Why do you care if it is solicited or unsolicited?  Knowing the law under which this matters could impact the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

**ASSUMING THIS IS A QUESTION OF U.S. SECURITIES LAWS**

You didn't explain whether you're related to the mother and son, but I'll assume you are.  If that's the case, this really wouldn't qualify as a solicited sale.  It wasn't advertised publicly for sale, and there is already (I assume) a long-standing relationship between the parties.  In such a case, this would be a perfectly legal and normal type of transaction, so I can't see any reason for concern.

*That being said*, you would be wise to contact the state securities regulation agency where you live to ensure you're on firm ground.

The law pertaining to the solicited sale of securities normally targets instances where people are trying to do private stock offerings and are seeking investors, in which case there are a number of different state and federal agencies and regulations that come into play.  The situation you've described does not fall under these types of scenarios.

Good luck!